# Сравнивание объектов через instanceof

Tags: java, интерфейс

Есть метод, которому в качестве аргумента может передаться объект любого класса, данный метод должен проверить посредством instanceof к какому классу принадлежит передаваемый объект:

```
public class Alligator implements Predator {}

public class Panda implements Herbivore {}

public class Check{
    Object naturalEnemy = new Alligator();// Проверяемый по умолчанию класс, !!!!может изменятся!!!!!!
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(""+checkAnimal(new Alligator()));//
        System.out.println(""+checkAnimal(new Panda()));
    }
    public boolean checkAnimal(Object animal){
        if(naturalEnemy instanceof animal.getClass()) return true;// Не работает :(
        //if(naturalEnemy instanceof Predator) return true;// Работает, но подобный подход не приемлим.
    }
}
```

Подвох в том что ни один из сравниваемых объектов не известен, и выводить клас в текстовую строку тоже не приемлимо.
Помогите кто чем может.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А откуда ограничение? Какую настоящую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Объясню еще подробнее: для того чтобы сделать возможным легкую проверку я создал много интерфейсов: хищник/травоядное(или оба одновременно), летающее/земноводное/наземное.
Животному его естественный враг передается объектом при сканировании пространства, поэтому лучшим способом проверить его был бы оператор "instanceof" он проверяет сам класс и все интерфейсы реализованные им.
Конечно можно преобразовать классы в текстовую строку и сравнить, но количество кода значительно возрастет.

Comment: Зачем вы передаете экземпляр natural enemy? Вы должны передавать сам класс, насколько понимаю, instanceof при этом должен вполне себе корректно работать.

Comment: @Etki **instanceof** для этого не предназначен. Тут **класс для проверки динамический**. А вот передавать именно класс, а не объект класса было бы правильнее

Comment: @cache что значит динамический класс? Про экземпляр - именно это я и написал, нет?

Comment: @Etki, Мы можем сказать `obj instanceof java.lang.String`, но не можем `Class<?> myclass = String.class; obj instamceof myclass;` (код попросту не скомпилируется). Зато можем проверить, `myclass.isInstance(obj) ;` так вот, для этой проверки нам не нужен экземпляр класса, достаточно самого класса, как Вы и сказали

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD 3:**
Вместо `instanceof` используйте `Class.isInstance`. `instanceof` тут неприменим

То есть Вашу проверку

```
if(naturalEnemy instanceof animal.getClass()) return true;
```

нужно заменить на

```
return naturalEnemy.getCLass().isInstance(animal);
```

или на

```
animal.getCLass().isInstance(naturalEnemy);
```

в зависимости от того, какое из животных Вы проверяете

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

сделайте абстрактный класс 
 `abstract class Animal` и всех животных наследовать от него.

```
public class Predator extends Animal
```

а потом проверять

```
if(naturalEnemy instanceof Animal)
```

Comment: В оригнинальной программе так и есть, все классы животных наследуются от одного, но потом по мере снижения обрастают интерфейсами типа "хищник" и "травоядное" и для каждого есть свой специфический природный враг, поэтому (например) в классе "панда" предустановлена ссылка на объект в которую передается хищник, потом при обзоре местности панда должна сравнить обнаруженное животное с своим природным врагом,

Comment: но так как объект "природный враг" определен в родительском классе "Animal" то природный враг для каждого животного определяется через конструктор, поэтому ни класс природного врага, ни класс обнаруженого животного заранее определить нет возможности.